# React Native: Error Message undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So I am trying to get the screen to change to a different screen when a user signs up. But at the moment I get the error `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')`. I can add users to the database but the screen refuses to change once they have been added.

I have tried using `import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';` but it just throws me some different errors. The navigation only seems to work on the screens and when it is attached to a button. I am yet to get it working on a function when a user has just signed up. The expected outcome should be that a user signs up and then it changes to an accounts page for example.

**AuthContext.js**

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import createDataContext from './createDataContext';
import trackerAPI from '../../api/tracker';
// import { navigate } from '../navigationRef';

const authReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'add_error':
            return { ...state, errorMessage: action.payload };
        case 'signup':
            return { errorMessage: '', token: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const signup = (dispatch) => {
    return async ({ email, password, navigation }) => {
        try {
            const response = await trackerAPI.post('/signup', { email, password });
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
            dispatch({ type: 'signup', payload: response.data.token });
            navigation.navigate('TrackDetail');
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error Message', error.message);
            dispatch({ type: 'add_error', payload: 'Something went wrong :(' });
        }
    };
};

const signin = (dispatch) => {
    return ({ email, password }) => {};
};

const signout = (dispatch) => {
    return () => {};
};

export const { Provider, Context } = createDataContext(
    authReducer,
    { signin, signout, signup },
    { token: null, errorMessage: '' }
);
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import { setNavigator } from './src/navigationRef';

const Index = () => {
    return (
        <App
            ref={(navigator) => {
                setNavigator(navigator);
            }}
        />
    );
};

export default Index;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import AccountScreen from './src/screens/AccountScreen';
import SigninScreen from './src/screens/SigninScreen';
import SignupScreen from './src/screens/SignupScreen';
import TrackDetailScreen from './src/screens/TrackDetailScreen';
import { Provider as AuthProvider } from './src/context/AuthContext';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <>
                    <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SigninScreen} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignupScreen} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="TrackDetail" component={TrackDetailScreen} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="Accounts" component={AccountScreen} />
                </>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};

export default () => {
    return (
        <AuthProvider>
            <App />
        </AuthProvider>
    );
};
```

Comment: useNavigation works inside a NavigationContainer and in your setup you have AuthProvider which it outside of NavigationContainer.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the navigation.navigate() function.
In my case, I used to call navigation.navigate() after calling props function.
For example:

```
props.signup(email, password, () => {navigation.navigate('TrackDetail')});
```